# AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'norm_resid'

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

When I run this I have the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'norm_resid'
```

I have the latest version of OLS, so the attribute `norm_resid` should be there.

Any ideas ?

```
from scipy import stats
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
"""
Data Management
"""
data = pd.read_csv("TestExer1-sales-round1.csv")
X_train = data["Advertising"]
Y_train  = data["Sales"]


# use of linregregress
model = ols("Y_train ~ X_train", data).fit()
print(model.summary()) 

plt.plot(X_train,Y_train , 'ro')
plt.plot(X_train, model.fittedvalues, 'b')
plt.legend(['Sales', 'Advertising'])
plt.ylim(0, 70)
plt.xlim(5, 18)
plt.hist(model.norm_resid())
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Normalized residuals')

plt.xlabel('Temperature')
plt.ylabel('Gas')
plt.title('Before Insulation')
```

Comment: Why do you think there should be a norm_resid attribute?

Comment: The question references code at  http://mpastell.com/2013/04/19/python_regression/ which uses statsmodels version 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but the following worked:

`plt.hist(model.resid_pearson)`

Thus your solution should look like:

```
from scipy import stats
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
"""
Data Management
"""
data = pd.read_csv("TestExer1-sales-round1.csv")
X_train = data["Advertising"]
Y_train  = data["Sales"]


# use of linregregress
model = ols("Y_train ~ X_train", data).fit()
print(model.summary()) 

plt.plot(X_train,Y_train , 'ro')
plt.plot(X_train, model.fittedvalues, 'b')
plt.legend(['Sales', 'Advertising'])
plt.ylim(0, 70)
plt.xlim(5, 18)
plt.hist(model.resid_pearson)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Normalized residuals')

plt.xlabel('Temperature')
plt.ylabel('Gas')
plt.title('Before Insulation')
```

when using statsmodel version 0.8.0 or greater.

Note: the pearson residuals only divide each residual value with standard error of residuals. While normalisation also divides each residual by the sum of all residuals. For more see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110615)

From the [docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.resid_pearson.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.resid_pearson).

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Comment: It appears that the name was changed from `norm_resid` to `resid_pearson`. See [commit log](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/commit/f8745fbed150fb54952c8d0d423215227018624c)